# An integral representation in the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, greens-theorem

I was experimenting with some complex analysis and i have some problems with my considerations.

Consider $f$ holomorphic ,with $f : \Omega_1\to \Omega_2 ,$ where both $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ are open sets that contain the unit disc $\mathbb{D} $ ,then using the fact that $z=\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ and  Green's theorem for every ,$ a\ne z ,$ with $|a|<1$ , I find that: 
$$\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}\left(-\frac{1}{z}+\log\left(1-\frac{a}{z}\right) \left(\bar{a}+\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)f(z)dz=2i\int\int_{\mathbb{D}}\frac{\bar{z}-\bar{a}}{1-a\bar{z}}f(z)dxdy.$$
I have done all the calculations (not so many but that is not my question) and I find the above result which also can be written (using Cauchy's integral formula) as:
$$2i\int\int_{\mathbb{D}}\frac{\bar{z}-\bar{a}}{1-a\bar{z}}f(z)dxdy=\left(\bar{a}+\frac{1}{a}\right)\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}\left(\log\left(1-\frac{a}{z}\right) \right)f(z)dz-\frac{f(0)}{a}.$$

MY QUESTION: Do i have the right to use Green's theorem here? Is the logarithm here well defined ? Can someone verify, or help me with this one?

Comment: Wouldn't the last term be $i 2 \pi f(0)/a$?

Comment: I have simplified the pi's as you can see. Are my calculations ok except for that? Can i apply Greens theorem?

Comment: Perhaps a statement of Green's theorem would help.

Comment: What i need is the integrated function to be smooth inside the unit disc. Is it much to ask you to make the same calculations to see your result?

Comment: A problem exists when $z=a$ , but how can i overcome this difficulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the logarithm is well defined.

Since $|\frac{a}{z}|< 1$ for $a$ with $|a|<1$ and $ z\in \partial \mathbb{D}$, we have
$$
\operatorname{Re}\, \left(1-\frac{a}{z}\right)>0.$$
Thus $\log \left(1-\frac{a}{z}\right)$
is well defined for $ z\in \partial \mathbb{D}$ (NOT for $z\in\mathbb{D}$) and the expression$$
\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}\left(-\frac{1}{z}+\log\left(1-\frac{a}{z}\right) \left(\bar{a}+\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)f(z)dz
$$
is defined meaningfully.

Also you have the right to use Green's theorem.

Since $z\bar{z}=1$ for $z\in\partial \mathbb{D}$ we can rewrite $$
\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}\left(-\frac{1}{z}+\log\left(1-\frac{a}{z}\right) \left(\bar{a}+\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)f(z)dz
$$
as
$$\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}\left(-\bar{z}+\log\left(1-a\bar{z}\right) \left(\bar{a}+\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)f(z)dz.
$$
Since $\log (1-a\bar{z})$ is well defined for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$, we can use Green's theorem to get 
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}\left(-\bar{z}+\log\left(1-a\bar{z}\right) \left(\bar{a}+\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)f(z)dz&=2i\iint_\mathbb{D}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\left\{\left(-\bar{z}+\log\left(1-a\bar{z}\right) \left(\bar{a}+\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)f(z)\right\}dxdy\\
&=2i\iint_\mathbb{D}\left(-1+\frac{-a}{1-a\bar{z}}\cdot\left(\bar{a}+\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)f(z)\,dxdy.
\end{align}

Comment: This is exactly the answer that i wanted. Thank you , i was thinking the exact same things but i had some doubts. I changed the signs a bit in the contour integral and i corrected it a bit. I want to have an automorphism of the unit disc inside the double integral in order to find an estimation lemma . What do you think?

Comment: If we start at the integral $$
I=\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}}\left(-\frac{1}{z}+\log\left(1-\frac{a}{z}\right) \left(\bar{a}-\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)f(z)dz,
$$
then we have \begin{align}
I
&=2i\iint_\mathbb{D}\left(-1+\frac{-a}{1-a\bar{z}}\cdot\left(\bar{a}-\frac{1}{a}\right)\right)f(z)\,dxdy\\
&=2ai\iint_\mathbb{D} \frac{\bar{z}-\bar{a}}{1-a\bar{z}}f(z)dxdy.
\end{align}

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i have done to correct it , thanks.

Comment: Now i can take modules to both parts $$\left|\int_{\partial\mathbb{D}} \left( \bar{a}-\frac{1}{a}\right)\log\left(1-\frac{a}{z} \right)f(z)dz\right|\le |f(0)|+\int\int_{\mathbb{D}}|f(z)|dxdy$$ because the automorphism has module less than 1 . And now i want to get something for the left integral in order to finish the job. I skipped some $\pi i$ s intentionally.

Comment: You will succeed soon. It's my great pleasure.

Comment: I guess this is what research looks like in the real world :P